# curl api redirects to another page on success

Tags: php, php-curl

I am working on an getting a data from an api, on errors it responds with a JSON data but in success it redirects to a different url with get data variables and in that url contains the json success datas.

Is there work around on this on how i can get the success data without my page redirecting?

sample of the url when the response is success:
samplesite/api?message=0&code=0

```
$url = "urlprovided";

 $fields = [
"Username" => "sample",
"Password" => "sample",];


 $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 

 //execute
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 $array = json_decode($result, true);
 var_dump($array);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not sure I understand your question. To my knowledge, curl is mostly a client library, meaning that you are fetching data from a server. That server tells you 'Your data is another castle' and curl...fails to follow the redirect? Or does it and you'd rather not have it redirect? In either case, you'll need to adjust the server to stop sending redirect requests.

Comment: id rather not have it redirect and get the data from that different url in the same code

Comment: Well, as I said before, it's the server telling you 'to go there and fetch your data', so you'll have very little choice in the matter. You can tell CURL to follow a redirect HTTP code to 'the other side', but that's all you can do in this situation.
If this redirect is part of the API, it is what you need to work with.

Either that, or change the API (if you can).